# facing issue while geting form radio buttons data

Tags: php, html, forms

I have multiple fields and created clones using jQuery. When I attempt to receive form data in PHP, all input data is received correctly. However, when it comes to radio buttons, only the response from the first field is received accurately. For the rest of the fields, I am receiving a value of 0.

My HTML Code

```
    <div class="row">    
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="form-group optbox">
        <input type="radio" value="1" name="mcq[0]">
        <input type="text" name="opt-a[0]" placeholder="Option 1" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="form-group optbox">
            <input type="radio" value="2" name="mcq[0]">
        <input type="text" name="opt-b[0]" placeholder="Option 2" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        
        <div class="form-group optbox">
            <input type="radio" value="3" name="mcq[0]" >
        <input type="text" name="opt-c[0]" placeholder="Option 3" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="row">    
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="form-group optbox">
        <input type="radio" value="1" name="mcq[1]">
        <input type="text" name="opt-a[1]" placeholder="Option 1" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="form-group optbox">
            <input type="radio" value="2" name="mcq[1]">
        <input type="text" name="opt-b[1]" placeholder="Option 2" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        
        <div class="form-group optbox">
            <input type="radio" value="3" name="mcq[1]" >
        <input type="text" name="opt-c[1]" placeholder="Option 3" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my PHP Coee:

```
$opts1 = $_POST['opt-a'];
$opts2 = $_POST['opt-b'];
$opts3 = $_POST['opt-c'];
$correct = $_POST['mcq'];
var_dump($correct);
```

result for var_dump

```
array(2) {[0]=>string(1) "3" [1]=> string(0) ""}
```

for radio button 1st value is correct but 2nd value is null

Comment: `$_POST[$mcq]` yes, you can also use `<input name="mcq[0]">` or even `<input name="mcq[]">`  to create arays of form inputs.

Comment: @brombeer i tried this as well. no result.

Comment: Also it might be useful to show us the HTML form (and any related JS/jQuery code) you're using to submit data to the script, so we can check you've implemented this in such a way that will send data to the server in the format that the PHP script is designed to deal with. Always post a [mre] of your issue (see also [ask]).

Comment: `is it possible to in php to receive form data with variable?`...the short answer to this is  "yes", but that isn't really your actual question. I suggest making a more meaningful title for the benefit of future readers, and also people who might choose to look at this question and attempt to answer it. (For background, take a look at [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question)).

Answer (score 2):

By using the same name you will always get the value of the last input element.
Use a name that describes an array, like:

```
<input type="text" name="mcq[]" />
```

In PHP, if you need to iterate over all this values, just use:

```
foreach ($_POST["mcq"] as $value) {
   $correct = $value;
}
```

Or with the while:

```
$n = 5; $j = 0;
$mcq = $_POST['mcq'];
while ($j <= $n) {
   $correct = $mcq[$j];
   $j++;
}
```

Comment: I am guessing that's how this actually started, because that's what they were using here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76505631/1427878 But instead of trying to follow through and develop that into a _proper_ solution, I guess they are exploring "alternative ways" now.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 $n = 5;
 $j = 0;
    while ($j <= $n) {
        $mcq = "mcq".$j;
        $correct = $_POST[$mcq];
        $j++;
    }
```

Comment: You'll get a more favourable response to your post if you take the time to explain your answer, including what you've done and why you expect that it solves the problem. Just dumping code is actually not very helpful most of the time. See also [answer]. Thanks.